# How can I implement polymorphism in C++ for a wrapper class that will hold one of several types?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am an accomplished C programmer, and I have written an assembler and VM in C (https://github.com/chucktilbury/assembler (mostly working but not complete)) and I am thinking of porting it to C++ so I can use the STL for obvious reasons. This is a hobby project with no expectations of actually being useful to anyone.

My VM has a notion of a Value, which can have exactly one of several types. I have implemented it using a struct with a union embedded in it. This has led to a bunch of huge macros to do simple things like addition and comparisons.

What I would like to do is have a base class that can be used to reference a Value and child classes that implement the specific type so that I don't have to spell out exactly how to retrieve the data that the Value implements.

In other words, This is what I have:

```
    ...
    switch(left_val->type) {
        ...
        case FLOAT:
            switch(right_val->type) {
            ...
                case INTEGER:
                    result->type = FLOAT;
                    result->data.float_val = left_val->data.float_val + right_val->data.int_val;
                    break;
            ...
            }
        ...
    }
```

What I would like to see:

```
  result->add(left_val, right_val); // over-simplified, I know....
```

Obviously, I can do this like I did it in C, and that's my knee-jerk reaction. But I feel that I am missing some major point of how this **should** work in C++.

As I understand it, there is no way to achieve what I want because C++ (like C) is a statically typed language. I may as well just encapsulate the ugly in a single class and just pass around Value(s) as I am currently doing in C.

Is there general agreement with that statement? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: _"a struct with a union embedded in it"_ - You may want to look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). What should the result be if the left type is a `FLOAT` and the right type is an `INTEGER`? `FLOAT` I guess?

Comment: Well, to start with, in C++ you wouldn't write `result->add(left_val, right_val)`. Instead you would overload `+` and simply write `result=left_val+right_val`. There are several different possible approaches to implement something like that; however an optimal approach depends very much on specific details and everything else that needs to be implemented, so it's not really possible to, authoritatively, answer something like this.

Comment: Sam, Yes. the form of ```result = lhv + rhv;``` is actually the result that I am looking for. To implement that, I would need to define overloads for every permutation of the left and right Value, including those that result in an error. Is that correct? Did I miss something?

Comment: (1) You would only need to add overloads for types that don't have built-in `operator+` in C++.  (2) You don't have to add an overload for every error combination, you can write one that catches all errors.

Answer (score 26):

I suggest using a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to reduce the boilerplate.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>

using INTEGER = std::intmax_t;
using FLOAT = long double;

using Value = std::variant<INTEGER, FLOAT>;

auto operator+(const Value& lhs, const Value& rhs) {
    return std::visit([](auto&& l, auto&& r) -> Value { return l + r; }, lhs, rhs);
}
```

Now adding two `INTEGER`s would produce a `variant` holding an `INTEGER`. Involving a `FLOAT` in the addition would make the result `FLOAT`, just like in the normal rules of the language.

Example usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    Value i = 10;
    Value f = 3.14159;

    auto r = i + f;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KEdq74YxY)

A C++20 version (kindly provided by user17732522):

```
auto operator+(const Value& lhs, const Value& rhs) {
    return std::visit<Value>(std::plus{}, lhs, rhs);
}
```

---

A more generic version supporting mixing non-types and user-defined types will not use any fundamental (or `std::`) types directly in the `variant`:

```
template<class... Ts>
std::variant<Ts...> operator+(const std::variant<Ts...>& lhs,
                              const std::variant<Ts...>& rhs) {
    return std::visit<std::variant<Ts...>>(std::plus{}, lhs, rhs);
}
```

Then create user-defined types and define `Value` as a `variant` that can hold one of those types. Here's an example with a few of the types you mentioned in the comments:

```
struct Error {};
struct Number {};
struct String {};
struct Hash {};

using Value = std::variant<Error, Number, String, Hash>;
```

If the types have something in common, you could also add inheritance, but for now, this will suffice.
You must also decide what should happen for all combinations involving these types. I'd create a table for all operators you aim to support to think it through properly before implementing it. It could look like this for `operator+`:

| ↓ lhs + rhs → | Number | String | Hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Number** | Number | String | Error |
| **String** | String | String | Error |
| **Hash** | Error | Error | Hash |

I've left the `Error` row and column out because anything involving an operation with `Error` should most likely result in `Error`. If you disagree, add `Error` to the table too.

Now implement the overloads that satisfies this table. The below can most likely be refined using more templates to cover multiple cases but this shows overloads that needs to exist one way or another:

```
// if at least one operand is Error, return Error
Error operator+(const Error&, const Error&) { return {}; }
template<class T> Error operator+(const Error&, const T&) { return {}; }
template<class T> Error operator+(const T&, const Error&) { return {}; }

// valid Number operations:
Number operator+(const Number&, const Number&) { /*impl*/ }
String operator+(const Number&, const String&) { /*impl*/ }
// anything else return Error
Error operator+(const Number&, const Hash&) { return {}; }

// valid String operations:
String operator+(const String&, const String&) { /*impl*/ }
String operator+(const String&, const Number&) { /*impl*/ }
// anything else return Error
Error operator+(const String&, const Hash&) { return {}; }

// valid Hash operations:
Hash operator+(const Hash&, const Hash&) { /*impl*/ }
// anything else return Error
Error operator+(const Hash&, const Number&) { return {}; }
Error operator+(const Hash&, const String&) { return {}; }
```

If you forget one overload, your compiler will tell you - which is very nice. The visitor in the `operator+` taking `variant`s needs the table of operators to call to be exhaustive.

Then repeat for the other operators, with `std::visit`ors using `std::minus`, `std::multiplies` and `std::divides`. It's tedious work but you do not need to implement the actual logic to lookup the correct overload. The visitors will build the complete table for you and you'll only have to implement one operator overload at a time according to the matrices for the operators you've made.

Extending it is also pretty straight forwad. You add the new type to your operator matrices and to `Value` and then implement the missing operators. Again, the compiler will be most helpful and point out if you miss anything.

---

One way to reduce *some* of the implementation work could be to make some types convertible to others. If for example a `String + Number` should result in converting the `Number` to `String` and then performing the `String + String` operation, you could do this:

```
struct Error {};
struct Number { };
struct String {
    String() = default;
    String(const Number&) {} // converting constructor
};
struct Hash {};
```

Now these implementations can simply be removed:

```
String operator+(const Number&, const String&) { /*impl*/ }
String operator+(const String&, const Number&) { /*impl*/ }
```

Thinking about such valid conversions may reduce the workload considerably.

Comment: Great answer. I downloaded the demo and have been playing with it. There is a lot for me to unpack in the example, so forgive me if I missed something. 

When I add a std::string to the variant, it breaks the '+' operator. This is a big part of the problem I am trying to solve. In the VM, all data objects are a Value. That means that things like registers and the stack have to hold not only numbers, but any data type, including user defined types.

Comment: @chuckt Is `+` supposed to be supported for all types in `Value`? If so, what should the result be if you add a `FLOAT` to a `STRING`? A `STRING`?

Comment: Yes, a FLOAT + STRING results in a STRING value. A FLOAT * STRING results in an ERROR, which is also a valid native type. I also plan to support user defined types which may implement an arithmetic or comparison operator.

Comment: Use `if constexpr` in the **visitor** ***generic lambda*** to handle corner cases: `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<decltype(rhs), const double &>) return xyz;`

Comment: @Red.Wave Yes, that's one possibility, but it'll be a bit cumbersome if user-defined types are to be supported. One wouldn't want to modify the visitor each time a new type is added - I think. I'm leaning towards separate overloads ... but I'm still at work :-) Have to look at it in a few hours.

Comment: @chuckt I find it tricky to get it nice and user-friendly. I picture a namespace with the operator overloads for `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` that all have similar visitors like in the answer. To that I want to make it simple to add operator overloads for the specific types to a separate, user-defined, namespace that should then be found via ADL. I haven't designed much like that before so [what I've got so far](https://godbolt.org/z/abn7srr5d) is terribly cludgy. I'll look more into it for sure but I'll have to give it a rest for now.

Comment: To me, it looks like the central problem is that the return type has to be inferred from the types of the parameters. It's a fairly complex matrix, just for arithmetic. And, what if an operation on a user-defined type yields another user-defined type? In C, it's just wading in a sea of pointers. Normal stuff that looks like all the other stuff. I am really wondering if it's more trouble than it's worth, or to put that another way, maybe C really is the right choice for this. After all, I could just use the STL as an extension of C. The purists will hate it, but it will work and be maintainable

Comment: @chuckt For the fundamental types the return type will be automatically deduced from the arguments. What's needed is to define operator overloads that defines what type `X op Y` for all combinations involving user-defined types should return (in this context, `std::string` is a user-defined type). That may become a lot for sure, but once the framework is in place, adding overloads for new types should be easy (albeit tedious).  One could possibly add a greedy overload that returns `ERROR` as a fallback for all overloads not implemented to let this thing evolve gradually.

Comment: One may also use inheritance in case there are a lot of _is-a_ relations, which may reduce the number of overloads one has to add. On that topic - how many types do you currently support and how many do you expect will be needed? If you have a list of the types (and a description if they are esoteric) it may give a hint of future problems using my idea.

Comment: Planned types are Error, Nothing, Number, String, Boolean, List, and Hash. All of these are supported via the notion of a trap. For example, a trap is entered to add a list item. There is no overriding supported for these types. User defined types (from the user's point of view) are supported via a combination of traps and code that is defined in the assembly language. I also (plan to) support inline assembly and loading dynamic libraries from user's code.

Comment: @chuckt Ok, in the code you show `FLOAT` and `INTEGER` but you'll replace that with `Number`, that carries a `double` then? Conversion-wise, could you make a matrix of what should happen if you use the misc operators on combinations of the types? It'd help visualize the depth of the problem. I'm now exploring the idea to make a small wrapper template that can be used by all types which defines what the type can be converted into. Example,a  `wrapper<double>` would have an `operator wrapper<std::string> () const { return std::to_string(..); }`

Comment: making it possible to only define `operator+-*/` overloads when `lhs` and `rhs` are convertible to same type. At least that's an idea that would simplify it I think. If you haven't built tables here on SO before, i could put your types in a table in your question and you can fill it in.

Comment: @TedLyngmo make up your mind: do we have a generic expression that covers all possible combinations of 2 operands? Or we need special treatment of some individual cases? In either case IMO, a concentrated definition is more robust than spatterinng it among multiple overloads. This problem has similarities to multiple dispatch. Breaking the visitor into 2 layers and dealing with `rhs` and `lhs` separately, can be the way in some cases; but not all.

Comment: @Red.Wave It's hard to decide which way to go when I don't have the full picture, which is why I'm throwing out ideas for how to continue - and one way or another, all possible combinations _must_ be covered to get an `ERROR` instance instead of a compilation error for unsupported operations.

Comment: @Red.Wave ...  If the types and conversions that are to be supported are known when designing this (and they are not many), using _constexpr-if_ like you suggested could be an option. If the combinations are many and/or user-defined types are to be supported, I don't think putting it in the actual operator/visitor-code will be maintainable. I _think_ that one would like to keep that part stable.

Comment: So, really, in the existing code I do the type conversion before operations. I do it implicitly using switch/case. I tried some other scenarios involving tables of functions, but nothing works as well or is as easy to change as the switch/case, even if it is --really-- ugly. I will try and get a type-conversion matrix into the notes.md file tonight. The governing thought is about preserving the resolution of a value. Since a Value is a stand-alone object, then any type of value can be placed in a list or a hash. For example, number + list = list, where the number is prepended to the list.

Comment: Added the tables to the notes file in the repository.

Comment: @chuckt I'm not sure I understand the _"nothing works as well or is as easy to change as the switch/case"_ - The whole 2D switch-case-switch-case for `+` is replaced with `std::visit<std::variant<Ts...>>(std::plus{}, lhs, rhs);` and doesn't need to be changed ever.  Regarding the conversion matrices. You need one matrix per operator. I saw 2 matrices. Put the operator for which the matrix is valid in the top left corner of the matrix.

Comment: I should have said "nothing **I tried** works as well". The first table applies to --al-- binary arithmetic operations. The second table applies to --all-- casting operations, which are handled outside of the code that does arithmetic operations.

Comment: @chuckt Ok, my suggestion is to move cast rules into the actual classes and design the rules for each within its class like I showed with the `String` that can be constructed from a `Number`. You shouldn't need to manually implement these tables since you've got `std::visit` to create them for you. The implementation specific details for _how_ `std::visit` creates its internal table is different for different vendors, but I know some have thresholds for how many combinations that will be effective to instantiate one way and select methods accordingly. I think you'll find them close to optimal.

Comment: @chuckt and since at least some implementations builds the internal table differently depending on how many combinations of "things" you throw at it, it's saving you the job of refactoring your code when you reach a certain amount that would benefit from building the table in a slightly different way to make the lookup as quickly as possible.

Comment: It may be interesting to point out that one of the first iterations of this code was a table of functions, where each one performed any arithmetic operation based on the types of the parameters and returned a value of the correct type. Performance suffered for computation-heavy benchmarks, by more than 300%. Function calls and table lookups are pretty expensive in terms of CPU cycles and cache lines.

Comment: @chuckt Sure, you shouldn't throw your own `switch-case/switch-case` out without benchmarking. I expect that `std::visit` does at least as well as your handcrafted one, but - benchmarking is key.

Comment: @Ted.Lyngmo Thank you for being so patient with me. So... The upshot of all of this: It's going to be a lot of work to refactor 20K lines of code into a new language. The question is whether there is a reasonable expectation that the change will actually produce a useful result. (obvious statement, I know) The priorities are performance and maintainability, in that order. I would like to know your opinion on whether that change would be "worth it". Would you do it? I am new to C++, so I have to factor in the time to web search a bunch of stuff.

Comment: @chuckt _"Thank you for being so patient with me"_ - :-) No worries! I _think_ the change will be worth it but I would think more about how I would have designed this in C++ if I didn't have a lot of legacy code. In that case, going for the `std::varaint` + `std::visitor` would be my first choice. You could make stripped down version of what you've got now, only dealing with a few types and then make a version where you've converted those types to my suggested way of dealing withi it and then do some performace measurements to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

I have something very similar written in C++. I am assuming you have no expectation of performance. Here are some keypoints that might help:

You will need a way to store the type information for every piece of data. Instead of storing data type in an enum, you should use a class for this purpose. If you want to be able to support embedding additional types, your type system should be robust. Since I was aiming for an object oriented language, I have included data members and member functions (including operators and constructors) for types.

If you want to go built-in types only, you may register objects/classes to handle operators per type. Thus, once you have obtained a piece of data, you can get its type and invoke the necessary function. You may do this system using polymorphism but everytime you copy a the data, you will also copy the type. Therefore, you need to have a function that will clone your object properly. You could also go simpler route, but this will take more memory.

```
Type IntType() {
    Type t;
    t.addition = &add<int>;
    //...
    return t;
}
```

You can also create only one IntType and then distribute pointers of it for each data. Something similar to a vftable.

To actually store data, I have used my Any structure, it is very similar to std::any (I wrote this around 2014). You may use std::any for the data store. You have to be careful about types that cannot be copied.

If you want to see the project yourself, it is publically available at [here](https://repo.darkgaze.org/Gorgon/). You should get 4.x-dev branch. The system is in Source/Scripting. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at your project. Performance is a central requirement for Goldfish. Right now, my Fibonacci benchmark rivals Python3. See the link in the original post. Take a look at the notes to get a better idea of what I am trying to do.